# Is there any way to access jetty server logs through browser?

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I have configured jetty-distribution-9.4.11.v20180605 server on my ubuntu 16.04. Now I want to access jetty logs through browser using link localhost:8080/logs/. I have successfully configured this with tomcat web server, but not able to do the same on jetty server.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

A symlink should be enough.

If you have deployed to `${jetty.base}/webapps/` then just create a symlink.

Eg:

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ ln -s logs webapps/logs
```

Restart and you should be good.

Comment: I have tried your solution but logs are still not accessible through web browser.